# R: Handling of sf objects in raster package

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sf

Previously I was using `raster::crop` and `raster::mask` with shapefiles of class Spatial*, read in using `rgal::readOGR`.

I am just "upgrading" my scripts to use `sf` for reading and manipulating polygons.

#### raster::crop

`raster::crop` expects an 'extent' object as second argument. Up to now, this was automatically extracted from a Spatial* object. So I could just do `raster::crop(raster, polygon)`.
To get this working with an `sf` object, I can call `raster::crop(raster, as.vector(st_bbox(polygon)))` as an ugly workaround.

#### raster::mask

Since `raster::mask` clearly expects a `Raster* object or a Spatial* object` the only solution was to coerce the `sf` object back to a Spatial* object using `as("Spatial")`.

I assume this problem generalized to all `raster` functions? Did I overlook something or is it just the case that the `raster` package does not (yet) work with `sf` objects?

Comment: You don't want `as.vector(st_bbox(pnt_buf))` but rather `as.vector(st_bbox(pnt_buf))[c(1, 3, 2, 4)]`, because crop expects `c(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`

Answer (score 16):

For future reference, it works now! Here's some slightly modified example code from `?crop`, tested with **raster** [version 2.6-7](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html) which has been released on 2017-11-13.

```
library(raster)
library(sf)

r <- raster(nrow=45, ncol=90)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)

# crop Raster* with sf object
b <- as(extent(0, 8, 42, 50), 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(b) <- crs(r)
b <- st_as_sf(b) # convert polygons to 'sf' object
rb <- crop(r, b)

# mask Raster* with sf object
mb <- mask(r, b)
```

Comment: Can you print sf version, this yields Error in methods::validObject(y) : invalid class “Extent” object: TRUE, same raster version.

Comment: Sure @bw4sz, `packageVersion("sf")` is `‘0.6.4’`.

Comment: I'm still getting this error with sf `0.7.1` and raster `2.7.15` on OS X (Mojave). Did this get un-fixed?

Comment: worked for me today! sf 1.0-5 and raster 3.5.2 in R 4.1.0